# GORM TransientObjectException

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am being plagued by an

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException
```

using Grails 2.3.9 and Grails Hibernate 3 Plugin 3.6.10.15

Here's the specific issue:

I have a domain class called Pencil and a domain class Backpack with a many-to-many relationship:

```
 Pencil{
    PencilType type
    Location location
    Date creationDate
    String description
    int position
    boolean active

    static hasMany = [backpacks: BackPack]
    static belongTo = [backpacks: BackPack]

    static constraints = { .... all nullable ..... }
 }

 BackPack{
    Color color
    int size

    static hasMany = [pencils: Pencil]
    static belongsTo = [pencils: Pencil]

    static constraints = { .... all nullable ..... }
  }
```

If I create and save a pencil, I cannot save without getting the:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObject Exception
Message: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: Pencil
```

This occurs even when creating a blank pencil object.

```
 new Pencil().save()
```

--UPDATE--
**Problem occurs using both Hibernate3 and Hibernate4 Grails plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure you have properly demarcated your transactional boundaries with `@Transactional` or `withTransaction` for write operations.

Comment: In the service where I'm saving, I have static transactional = true and I just tested using @Transactional annotations and it still throws the transient instance exception. I rolled Grails back from 2.3.9 to 2.2.5 and it saves fine.

Comment: Also, I'm trying to upgrade to hibernate 4 to make sure it's not a hibernate 3 bug or something. However, I'm getting an error when using hibernate4. I've put up another question regarding that issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050291/grails-hibernate4-upgrade