# Grails Hibernate4 upgrade errors on getGeneratedKeys()

Tags: grails, grails-orm, hibernate-4.x

I'm upgrading to the Hibernate4:4.3.5.3 plugin for Grails 2.3.9 . However, I'm getting an error:

```
getGeneratedKeys() support is not enabled
```

I haven't been able to find any configuration details on how to enable this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I just found that you can configure it under DataSource.groovy in the hibernate{...} block

```
hibernate{
    jdbc.use_get_generated_keys = true
}
```

Comment: I wonder why this is not to be found in the Grails docs.. Can't make it work with H4 without this setting either... Grails 2.4.0, Hibernate 4, Oracle 11G, ojdbc6-11.2.0.4 and Java 7 64bit. Any ideas any one???